# Post data from a form in json format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, format

I have two html pages: `1.html` and `2.html`.
I want to post data from a form in `1.html` to `2.html`.
I want to store data from form in `1.html` in json and then post it to `2.html` without going to `2.html` when I click on submit button and parse json in `2.html` and use them.

Contents of `1.html`:

```
<body>
    <form action="2.html" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="material" value="material" readonly>
        <input type="text" name="Unit" value="Unit" readonly>
        <button type="submit" id="add">add</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Can anyone help? I need it soon. thanks

Comment: If the second page really is .html, then the request would be moot, as you cannot work with POST data in HTML alone. That aside, use `$.ajax` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: you can post data from the client to the server. When it arrives at the server you have to process it using a script, and then send a response back to the client. If "passing from 1 one page to 2nd page" is your thought process then you're conceptualising it wrong. A plain HTML page cannot do anything with a POST request. I suggest you take a tutorial about HTML forms, and then possibly follow it up with one about AJAX.You seem to be missing a basic understanding of the concepts and architecture involved.If you don't have a server-side script language yet (e.g. PHP) then you'll likely need one

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("your_backend_api.as", {suggest: txt}, function(result){
    $("span").html(result);
});
```

above {suggest : txt} is your json object.

Comment: I dont get it, can you please explain it more?

Comment: Please read this article once https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)